# Is there a way to verify that data files are not corrupted after reformatting?

Tags: windows-7, data-validation

Hi all I have  a `C:` and `D:` drive on one single physical hard disk, whereby windows is installed on `C:` and data is stored on `D:`

After reformatting my computer, how do i verify if after reinstalling windows on `C:`,

My `D:` files are safely unaffected?

(I mean when I look in D:, the files are there, however of course at a glance there's no way to tell if there are any "internal" errors with that drive)

Comment: Why are you worried about this exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound ? So that I could ensure that I do not have to recopy my 500 GB backup files (external HDD) back into the D: drive which may take a couple of hours to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a checksum of the disk contents and verify with a previous one to test whether disk contents have changed.

Answer (score 2):

Formatting the `C:` drive would have no effect on the contents of the `D:` drive, even if both volumes are present on the same physical drive.

If you want to check the integrity of the filesystem on `D:` you can invoke `chkdsk` to validate the filesystem's internal consistency (Start->Run->`chkdsk D:`->OK). There is no way to determine if a file that *should* be on D: is missing, however, unless you have an image or full directory listing of D: